# Fedora Incorrect Login when installing vm through qemu

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, login, qemu, emulation

I am trying to boot fedora vm on Linux Test Pc from qemu. It actually shows the temporary password for first login. But when I try that password it is saying Login is Incorrect.

I don't know why the password is showing incorrect although I entered the correct password.

I downloaded fedora cloud image from https://mirror.genesisadaptive.com/fedora/linux/releases/36/Cloud/x86_64/images/

The command I used is:

`sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system --name CXL-Test --memory 4096 --cpu host --vcpus 4 --os-variant fedora35 --import --graphics none --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/CXL-Test.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio --cloud-init`

The tutorial I am following is: https://stevescargall.com/blog/2022/01/20/how-to-emulate-cxl-devices-using-kvm-and-qemu/#configure-the-guest-os-using-a-cloud-init-boot-strap-image

The console shows:

```
Starting install...

Password for first root login is: gjxGCzxrSzkknlu4

Creating domain... | 0 B 00:00:00

Running text console command: virsh --connect qemu:///system console CXL-Test

Connected to domain 'CXL-Test'

Fedora Linux 36 (Cloud Edition)

Kernel 5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64 on an x86_64 (ttyS0)

fedora login: root

Password: Login incorrect
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem; using the same image it all seems to work as expected. You can see a complete run-through [here](https://asciinema.org/a/l4aL3JoVMbA8kRrt5PHJoXqKI). If you can't get the generated password to work, consider passing in an ssh public key using `--cloud-init ssh-key=/path/to/key.pub` (and then ssh-ing to `root@<vm ip address>`).

Comment: Are you sure the keyboard layout is what you expect?  Try typing that password at the login prompt to ensure you get the same characters shown, before you type them at the password prompt (where you can't see what's produced).